# Call a function that animates using CGAffineTransform sequentially

Tags: swift

I have a function, that animates moving of an UIImageView from source (x,y) coordinate to a destination.   The following code is called 8 times, one after another, from another a function:

```
    func callAnimate(deckImage:UIImage, imageViewFrame: CGRect, destination:CGPoint) {
        cardAnimationImageView = UIImageView(image: deckImage);
        cardAnimationImageView.frame = imageViewFrame;
        self.view.addSubview(cardAnimationImageView);
        
        doAnimate( cardAnimationImageView:self.cardAnimationImageView, destination:destination, completion: self.showCard);
    }
```

```
 func doAnimate( cardAnimationImageView: UIImageView, destination:CGPoint, completion: () -> Void) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0) {
            
        cardAnimationImageView.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: destination.x - 
        cardAnimationImageView.frame.origin.x - 60, y: destination.y - 
        cardAnimationImageView.frame.origin.y - 5)
        } completion: { _ in
            self.showCard()
        }
    }
func showCard() -> Void
    {
        currentCardDealtSeat.firstCardImageView.isHidden = false;
        currentCardDealtSeat.secondCardImageView.isHidden = false;
      //  self.view.sendSubviewToBack(currentCardDealtSeat.firstCardImageView);
       // self.view.sendSubviewToBack(currentCardDealtSeat.secondCardImageView);
        self.view.insertSubview(currentCardDealtSeat.firstCardImageView, belowSubview:currentCardDealtSeat.seatView);
        self.view.insertSubview(currentCardDealtSeat.secondCardImageView, belowSubview:currentCardDealtSeat.seatView);
        
        cardAnimationImageView.frame = CGRect.zero;
```

Here I face two problems:

1. All the animations occur at the same time. I want them to occur sequentially in the order which they are called. How do I achieve that?
2. Both currentCardDealtSeat.firstCardImageView and currentCardDealtSeat.secondCardImageView are placed in the background initially, and then hidden.  After the animation I want the object being animated hidden or removed, and make the above two views visible in the background. Currently when isHidden is set to false, both cards appear in the foreground, rather than the background.  I have tried sending them to the back, but that never happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

even if you call `UIView.animate` several times, it will run at the same time. so the best way would be:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5,
               delay: 0) {
    // your first animation here
}
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5,
               delay: 0.5) {
    // your second animation here
}
//and so on
```

Comment: This worked.  One question though.  After you animate the image how do you remove it (cardAnimationImageView)?

Comment: you can use the `completion` parameter on `UIView.animate` and set it there. if you want a more detailed answer, ask another question and post your code, please